# Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I am using http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justguy/archive/2009/01/19/wpf-combobox-with-checkboxes-as-items-it-will-even-update-on-the-fly.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

example to show selected items in the same combobox seperated by comma.

but when i try to use Usercontrol in wpfform i am getting this exception

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
Message=Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.
Source=PresentationFramework
LineNumber=0
LinePosition=0
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader,   XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at CheckboxInComboboxWpf.App.Main() in C:\test\CheckboxInComboboxWpf\CheckboxInComboboxWpf\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext,  ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
   InnerException: 
   Message=Cannot find resource named 'SolidBorderBrush'. Resource names are case sensitive.
   Source=PresentationFramework
   StackTrace:
        at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference)
        at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   InnerException:
```

Answer (score 55):

The problem is because of incorrect order of your styles. I mean that if we publish button style with reference on static resource `NormalBrush`, which is declared under the style, like this:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" >
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ButtonCont"></ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>       
</Style>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

This code will give you such error. But if you change, like this

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}" >
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ButtonCont"></ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>       
</Style>
```

Everything works fine. The same this occurs if your resources are stored in different xaml files and you attach them in your `ResourceDictionary`. For example (consider we store our `NormalBrush` in `Colors.xaml` and `Button` in `Button.xaml`). This gives error:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Button.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Colors.xaml" />
```

This should work error:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Colors.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Button.xaml" />
```

Comment: Will the order also cause this issue when I am using `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`?

Comment: @DROPtableusers Yes. I was myself surpriced, but yes. I suppose this is because the compiler reads the resources line by line. So if some of your dictinaries references the one, which is forward,, it simply can't find it, because it is not compiled yet.

Comment: interesting, thanks for your response.  I was having a similar issue but it was because I was trying to load a resource that wasn't there (surprisingly that does not work...)

Answer (score 11):

Please check if you have specified a converter in a Xaml that doesn't exist.

Comment: Same error when trying to use style which was not declared

Comment: In my case it was a StaticResource (a color) which doesn't exist in my Resources file App.xaml

Answer (score 6):

By using a `DynamicResource`instead of `StaticResource`, it will find the resource at runtime, so you don't have to worry about the order of the declarations in the XAML.

There may be downsides to this (?), but in particularly sticky cases, this has been the answer to my prayers.

Answer (score 5):

I had stumbled upon this exact problem. There is a problem with the XAML file. 
`SolidBorderBrush` is missing from the XAML. By adding it, the sample works fine.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#000" />
```

Bellow follows the complete contents of the XAML file.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.ComboWithCheckboxes"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
Height="22" Width="120"
x:Name="UserControl"
>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#000" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
              x:Name="Border" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              CornerRadius="2"
              Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="1" />
            <Border 
              Grid.Column="0"
              CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" 
              Margin="1" 
              Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" 
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
            <Path 
              x:Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"     
              Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Border 
                      Name="Border"
                      Padding="2"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox
    x:Name="CheckableCombo"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    MinWidth="120"
    MinHeight="20"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=ItemsSource}"
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DataContext}"
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Tag="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"
                      Click="CheckBox_Click"
                      />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Grid>
                <ToggleButton 
                    Name="ToggleButton" 
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                    Focusable="false"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    ClickMode="Press">
                </ToggleButton>
                <ContentPresenter
                    x:Name="Presenter"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                    Margin="3,3,23,3"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <ContentPresenter.Content>
                        <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Text,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
                    </ContentPresenter.Content>
                </ContentPresenter>
                <TextBox x:Name="EditableTextBox"
                    Style="{x:Null}" 
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Margin="3,3,23,3"
                    Focusable="True" 
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Visibility="Hidden"
                    IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                <Popup 
                    Name="Popup"
                    Placement="Bottom"
                    IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                    AllowsTransparency="True" 
                    Focusable="False"
                    PopupAnimation="Slide">
                    <Grid 
                              Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
               Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the permission for your resource.resx file. At top of your file you will find the dropdown known as Access Modifier : change its type to 'Public'